# Does debconf-set-selections automatically deletes values from debconf database once they are used?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, debconf

Consider the following typescript:

```
# export DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive"

# sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-community-server mysql-community-server/remove-data-dir boolean true"

# echo GET mysql-community-server/remove-data-dir | debconf-communicate
0 true

# apt purge mysql-*
...

# echo GET mysql-community-server/remove-data-dir | debconf-communicate
10 mysql-community-server/remove-data-dir doesn't exist

# sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 123456"

# sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password 123456"

# echo GET mysql-server/root_password | debconf-communicate
0 123456

# apt install mysql-server-5.6
...

# echo GET mysql-server/root_password | debconf-communicate
0
```

So, does `debconf-set-selections` does this automatically? Or it's install scripts that do this? Any other option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, packages generally purge questions owned by them when they are themselves purged. As for `mysql`'s password, `postinst` script explicitly clears it after installation to avoid it staying on disk. More info [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2016/11/msg00552.html) and [here](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2016/11/msg00086.html).